# Pass ID from a list to external URL using loadURL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having trouble with the syntax below.

```
function getMail($this) {
    console.log($this.closest("tr").attr("id"));
    loadURL("ajax/my_email-opened.php", $('#inbox-content > .table-wrap'));
}
```

The id for a selected row (as per the console.log) should attach to the URL `ajax/my_email-opened.php`, which processes a returns data to the div with `id=inbox-content`, the data being based on that `id`. The `id` should be retrievable in the `ajax/my-email_opened.php` file by a get (or post) statement.

Something like this:

```
function getMail($this) {
    loadURL("ajax/my_email-opened.php?id=$this.id", $('#inbox-content > .table-wrap'));
}
```

I have searched far and wide, and assume it is straightforward, but am unable to find the correct syntax.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the `id` value to the URL string. Try this:

```
function getMail($this) {
    var id = $this.closest("tr").prop("id");
    loadURL("ajax/my_email-opened.php?id=" + id, $('#inbox-content > .table-wrap'));
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for the super fast response - after a few hours of trying to solve it myself! :)